# How to configure a Windows Server 2008 along with a router?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, router, dhcp

I have network setup like the following diagram, how do I set the DHCP in server so that user can access Windows share and also access internet?

```
[server]<========>
[client1]<=======>[network switch]<==========>[router]<=======>internet
[client2]<=======>
[client3]<=======>
```

I have tried some ways on setting up the DHCP, but users can either only access server's share or internet, but not both:

1. Default gateway and DNS points to server. User can access server's share but cannot access internet.
2. Default gateway points to router. DNS points to server and router. User cannot access server's share.
3. Default gateway and DNS points to router. User can access internet but cannot access server's share.

Comment: Do server and clients on the same network?

Comment: @Gnouc, yes, same network, using only one network switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the router as your default gateway and just the server for DNS. The reason they can't get on the internet is probably a lack of a forwarder set up on your DNS server for resolving external names.

Open DNS Management, open your server properties, click the forwarder tab, add your router's IP as a forwarder.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!